# Eye matrix application

Tags: matlab, matrix, identity, octave

The following lines:

```
a=[1;2;10;9]
eye(10)(a,:)
```

return:

```
[1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0]
```

How does it work? Why did it get the value?

Answer (score 5):

It selects rows 1,2, 10 and 9 and all columns from the the 10x10 identity matrix.

Without an intermediate step like below, this gives a syntax error for me though. Did you skip that step or did the syntax for this change between Matlab versions?

```
a=[1;2;10;9];
eye(10)(a,:)
```

Yields `??? Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.`

This does give the matrix you posted:

```
e = eye(10); 
e(a,:)
```

Comment: octave online lets you do it without the intermediate step... don't have matlab here to test it though.

Comment: @tmpearce: Interesting difference. But at least matrix slicing/addressing should work the same.